# OpenSSL Error while trying to log in JIOTV in KODI

Tags: openssl, kodi

I've installed JIOTV plugin in Kodi. When I try to login I get the following OpenSSL FATAL error:

> OPENSSL_Uplink(00007FFBDFB8A860,08): no OPENSSL_Applink

[image: OpenSSL error]

What could be the problem? I already have OpenSSL installed in my system.